# Почему [ перенесённые ]?

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Вот перенёс [вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/849359/178988) на мету и ему в заголовок добавилось `[перенесённые]`:

> [image: скриншот]

Раньше же было `[перенесён]` или `[перенесено]`, насколько я помню.