# Как сравнивается заголовок вопроса с запретами?

Tags: дефект, поддержка, локализация, заголовок

В заголовке написано `[перенесённые]`, а в ошибке - `[перенесено]`. Почему так?

> [image: скриншот]

Comment: Потому что перевод изменили.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не имею доступа к коду, но судя по описанному поведению и наличии возможности посмотреть историю переводов, могу с достаточной уверенностью сказать, что производится обычная проверка на поиск подстроки ["[migrated]"](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40263642?q=key%3A038944bdf4e9ea278463f6ea239928ca), переведённой на русский.

При этом сама строка с текстом ошибки не склеивается, а [является самодостаточной](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/135624485?q=key%3A8c29d495c4451c8dd620d5c785d0f54c):

> Нельзя использовать [перенесено] в заголовке.

Т.к. "[migrated]" в текущем состоянии [снова](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7487/176217) переводится как "[перенесён]", я исправил перевод на:

> Нельзя использовать [перенесён] в заголовке.

Будет на сайта после обновления базы переводов и пересборки.

---

Дополнительно имеются ещё монолитные строки:

> Нельзя использовать [требует правки] в заголовке.
>
> Нельзя использовать [закрыт] в заголовке.

Но их менять не требуется.

Comment: А то, для чего использовалось `перенесённые` не поломалось?)

Comment: @Qwertiy я не знаю, это не я делал. Вообще, заходите в чатик, там уютно :)